# Possible to display shortcode based on the category?

Tags: functions, categories, shortcode

So, aside from creating individual WordPress Category PHP Pages, I'd much rather have a functions.php command that would insert shortcode when a Category has been selected.

How would I go about that, and is it indeed even possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Everything's possible, if you take the right approach.

What I've interpreted from your question is, that you want an specific shortcode to be added to your content when the post is in a special category. What you can do is to hook into `the_content` filter and add a shortcode, if the post is in a particular category.

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpse314950_add_shortcode' );
function wpse314950_add_shortcode( $content ){
    global $post;

    // Check if this particular post has that category
    if ( has_category( 'my_category', $post ) ) {
        $content .= do_shortcode( '[some-shortcode arg_1="123" arg_2="xyz"]' );
    }

}
```

There might also be more approaches, such as:

1. Adding a shortcode in the content automatically (using JS or jQuery)
   when the author chooses a category
2. Adding the shortcode to every post and then stripping it out on other categories

Comment: Thanks for that....I was also thinking that a CSS approach might work within a div...so that I place the [SHORT CODE] in a div that is hidden if the category ID is not present...does that sound like a great plan or too basic?

Comment: You're welcome! It can work. But two important questions: 1- How much does your shortcode add to page load? If it's a lot of contains image, not a good idea. 2- Does it contain sensitive information? If also true, again not a good idea.

Comment: Thanks Jack. Here's what I am trying to achieve: I have email capture forms that I'd like to display on certain categories. So, for example, if someone is viewing a post on say, for example, "apples" then a [SHORT CODE] would appear to encourage visitors to join the "fruit" newsletter. I hope that makes sense! Really the main point of doing this is to make my email marketing automation easier.

Comment: That's fine then, you can use CSS. As long as you don't output heavy or sensitive content that could be manipulated, you'll be fine.